# How do I change the name of my mac in the terminal app?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

The computer name is displayed as "unknown-" at the command prompt. How do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through

```
sudo hostname new_name
```

If `new_name` contains single quotes, then it should be surrounded with double quotes.

Comment: The hostname is usually set dynamically, so I don't consider this to be the ideal option.

Comment: Is there any way other to revert it if it gets set to 'unknown-***' though?

Comment: See the answers to the other question here: http://superuser.com/a/414903/48078