# OS X Terminal prompt changed

Tags: terminal, osx-mountain-lion

My terminal prompt on OS X 10.8.3 suddenly is not the machine or hostname anymore but something like:

```
minint-j4lfb2s:~
```

Where does that come from? I did not change it. How can that be?

Comment: What does your `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts` says?

Comment: Never touched that. It has the default entries I guess - (127.0.0.1 localhost, 255.255.255.255 broadcast, ::1 localhost, fe80::1%lo0 localhost)

Comment: Figured out now, that it always happens when I am sitting in the office (of my new client). Is that a nt-domain thing? Is that normal? Back home everthing is fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen on a few macs (including my own once), where the mac's "Computer Name"/"Local Hostname" gets corrupted.

Check System Preferences -> Sharing, and seem what the "Computer Name" text box. Then check the text under that to see if the "Local Hostname" is correct; if not, click the "Edit..." button to it's right.

Comment: "Computer name" and hostname - both present and correct. Hostname equals computer name plus ".local".

Answer (score 0):

The hostname can also be determined by a reverse DNS lookup (see [this thread](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-70445.html)).

You can set a static hostname with `sudo scutil --set HostName newname`. It adds or changes the `System:System:Hostname` key in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`. Another way is to add `HOSTNAME=newname` to `/etc/hostconfig`.

Related questions:

- [OS X Terminal showing incorrect hostname](https://superuser.com/questions/357159)
- [OS X computer name not matching what shows on Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552)

Comment: I am sure there are ways to set a hostname. Right now I am just scared and wonder how it happend. And where this cryptic name comes from - where is it defined. E.g. the key in the preferences.plist you mention is correct - it shows the same as in the System preferences.

Comment: I have had the same issue today. What was the reason in your case? I am also freaked out a little, since I am afraid someone might have obtained an access to my mac