# Incorrect hostname in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm2

[image]

I'm not sure why the hostname is now jessica-s-phone. I am on a public wifi, and some googling revealed that the hostname is set by a DNS, so is it possible my iTerm chose someones phone as the host?

Answer (score 5):

Hosts *can* receive their hostname via DHCP, but it's not terribly common. It's far more common that they get their IPv4 address via DHCP, and then do a reverse-DNS lookup to determine the hostname for that IP address.

To see if you happened to get your hostname via DHCP, run `ipconfig getpacket en1` (Replace `en1` with the correct BSD-level interface identifier for the Wi-Fi interface in question. Yes, OS X has an `ipconfig`, and no, it's not anything like Windows' `ipconfig`). At the bottom of the output will be a list of DHCP message options and their values. If you see "hostname" or "client fqdn", then sure enough, your DHCP server gave you your hostname.  If you don't see either, then you probably got it from DNS. In that case, look at what DNS server it pointed you at. It probably pointed you at a DNS server on the local network, perhaps built into the router itself.

Use `ifconfig en1` (again, replace `en1` if necessary) to see what IPv4 address you have on that interface. Use `host $IPADDR` (replace `$IPADDR` with your IPv4 address) to see what your current view of the DNS system thinks your hostname is.

Comment: Solid info, it's very helpful to me as well.  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly normal for this to occur; when you login Terminal remotely bash does a reverse DNS lookup. It will only be the same if the hostname is not specified on the network you're connecting from and there is no reply from the DHCP server, or the reverse lookup against the remote DNS server fails to resolve.

You can easily over-ride the default setting by using this command in Terminal:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName <your hostname>
```

You can check it by using:

```
nslookup nn.nn.nn.nn

( or )

host nn.nn.nn.nn
```

(where nn signifies your Mac's ip address)

- [A similar question was asked a while back on the Stack Exchange Apple site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/30552/10139), and this was my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not determined by `DNS`, but actually `DHCP` - likely to avoid conflicts on local networks.  You are apparently being treaded as a former connected client, perhaps the router decides based on MAC similarities (but that is just a guess).

If you want to disable that functionality, as `sudo` edit `/etc/hostconfig` with

```
HOSTNAME=<yourhostname>.local
```

Comment: So I am not magically tunneled into Jessica's phone? I was only slightly slightly worried about that possibility and mostly just confused. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Lol, that would be a pretty massive securitt oversight if you were!