# 'ls' command in terminal is showing all files and file permissions. How do I get back to normal with 'ls' showing only normal files and folders?

Tags: bash, mac, terminal, ls

Want to get the terminal back to bryce@macbookpro instead of bryce@machine and have the 'ls' command only show visible files and folders.

[image: 'ls' command results with hidden files and file permissions]

Comment: Maybe your `ls` is an alias, run `alias` to see if helps. You can set `PS1` and `alias 'ls=/usr/bin/ls'` in .bash_profile (or .bashrc).

Comment: As for "machine" in the prompt, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496644/macos-strange-terminal-prompt-tried-resetting-terminal) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/357159/osx-terminal-showing-incorrect-hostname).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have some alias defined. Find what it is by running:

```
alias ls
```

This must be defined somewhere in what of the startup scripts of your shell. For example in case of Bash, you could find the list of fils to look at in the **FILES** section near the end of `man bash`:

> ```
> /etc/profile
>       The systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells
> ~/.bash_profile
>       The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
> ~/.bashrc
>       The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
> ```

To temporarily bypass the alias, you could run `command ls` or `\ls`, or temporarily remove the alias with `unalias ls`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I accepted some files to get a local backend running at my new gig and did not catch the one changing my .bash_profile file... learning the hard way.